# Expanding variables in an AHK string?

Tags: string, autohotkey, dereference, variable-expansion

I’m stuck trying to figure out how to expand any variables in an AutoHotkey string. In my specific case, I read a line from a file and run it. The line may contain one or more variable references which need to be expanded before being passed to `Run`.

Here’s a couple of tests (that don’t work):

```
Foo:="%A_MyDocuments%\blah.txt"
Bar=%Foo%
MsgBox %Bar%

a=1
b:="%a%+1=2"
MsgBox % b
```

I spent the past two hours scouring the docs and the Internet and found nothing that worked. There were a couple of close-calls, but nothing that matches this scenario.

Comment: The string in your first example doesn't contain any variable names. I don't understand what the second example is about. Where is the Run command, how is it used?

Comment: what is the problem, what is it that does not work? what errors do you get? etc....

Comment: I think you are looking for the functionality of `eval` in AHK https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval. There are AutoHotkey implementations of that to be found on the internet. Other than that, I cannot think of an easy way to do it

Comment: @2501, `Foo` contains a reference to `A_MyDocuments` which is a *variable* that points to, well, I’ll generously assume you can figure the rest out. And in the second example, `b` contains a reference to `a` which is a *variable* containing the value `1`. These are stripped down examples that show what I am trying to get working. The `Run` command is irrelevant; it is standard practice to use output commands like `MsgBox` for examples.

Comment: @Blauhirn, the problem is that AHK complains about an invalid variable name because in the first example, it is trying to use `%A_MyDocuments%\blah.txt` as the name of a variable and in the second one, it is trying to use `%a%+1=2` as the name of a variable. In both cases, it is trying to use the full string as the name of a variable which is not what I want; I want only the variable reference to be expanded. So the first one should print something like `c:\users\foo\documents\blah.txt` and the second should print `1+1=2`.

Comment: @Blauhirn, Thanks; I’ll look into that. It seems odd though that there would be no way simpler way, especially considering that AHK has several different ways to assign, dereference, and expand variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a built-in function that can do this. The `Transform` command can expand variables easily:

```
Foo:="%A_MyDocuments%\blah.txt"
Bar=%Foo%
Transform, Bar, Deref, %Bar%
MsgBox %Bar% ; Displays something like C:\Users\Foobar\Documents\blah.txt

a=1
b:="%a%+1=2"
Transform, b, Deref, %b%
MsgBox % b ; Displays 1+1=2
```

Thank you [guest3456](https://autohotkey.com/boards/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=207) for [the help](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=85305#p85305).

Answer (score 0):

You have some ‘=’ and ‘:=’ confused.

Saying “B:=%A%+1=2" is a string and you are trying to ‘set’ the answer to 2 in the string instead of calculating?

Should be something like:

```
A = 1
B := A + 1
Msgbox, % B

Or 
A = 1
B = %A% + 1
Msgbox, % B

Or 
Foo = %A_MyDocuments% . “\blah.txt”
Bar := Foo
Msxbox, %Bar%
```

> Variable assignment 
>   https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/97097-faq-variables-dynamic-variables-literal-strings-and-stuff-like-that/

Comment: I am familiar with expression and non-expression syntax. Like I said in the question, I am reading the strings from a file, so your examples will not work.

Comment: You do not specify what you are reading from a file or how you are reading it, which could impact my original response.  Only that you are stuck and trying to ‘expand variables’.   It does not makes sense to have %a%+1=2 output as a string showing “1+1=2”, because as a response it would be invalid unless ‘A’ always equaled ‘1’– but I imagine you don’t care about that.   The answer of: “Foo = %A_MyDocuments% . “\blah.txt”” should function and a line of ‘Msgbox % Foo’ should display the  ‘c:\users\foo\documents\blah.txt’.  I was suggesting that maybe your approach was a bit off, and not code.

Comment: I’m not sure where the confusion is, very first couple of lines said `I read a line from a file… the line may contain variables which need to be expanded`. It seems like a straight forward question. I used `:=` in the example to make sure that the variables actually contain the un-expanded variables. Reading from a file would have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way of doing this. I see two options. 
Use AutoHotkey.dll to evaluate your expression or run another instance of AutoHotkey.exe to the job for you.

For example:

```
Foo:="%A_MyDocuments%\blah.txt"
Bar := Eval(Foo)
MsgBox %Bar%

Eval(exp) {
    Static tempScript := A_ScriptDir "\tmp_eval.ahk"
    Static tempOutput := A_ScriptDir "\tmp_eval_out.txt"
    FileDelete, %tempScript%
    FileDelete, %tempOutput%
    FileAppend, % "FileAppend, " exp ", " tempOutput , %tempScript%
    RunWait, %A_AhkPath% "%tempScript%"
    FileRead, output, %tempOutput%
    FileDelete, %tempScript%
    FileDelete, %tempOutput%
    Return output
}
```

Comment: this will not work if `exp` contains a non-standard variable, like OPs `exp:="%a%"`

Comment: True. But since the "string" comes from a file, I'd assume that there is a certain set of variables that can be used in this string and these variables could simply be passed to the temporary ahk.exe instance.

Comment: It might also be possible to parse the output of ListVars and all of them over.

Comment: Wow, it seems so strange that there is no way to do this. I don’t think it is an unusual scenario. Maybe I should add it to the wish-list. In the meantime, I will try out your solution (or maybe just end up hard-coding the paths). `:-/`